# Returning total value of object property from array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to get the total value `totalPurchaseSum` of an property `stockPurchasePrice` from all objects in an array `arrPurchaseActions`.

This are the properties (user.h):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrPurchaseActions;

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat totalSumPurchased;

-(CGFloat)totalSumPurchased:(CGFloat)stockPurchasePrice;
```

This is the method I am trying to use (User.m):

```
-(CGFloat)totalSumPurchased:(CGFloat)stockPurchasePrice
{
    CGFloat totalSumPurchased = 0;
    size_t count = [self.arrPurchaseActions count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSumPurchased = totalSumPurchased +        [[self.arrPurchaseActions[i].stockPurchasePrice];
}

    return totalSumPurchased;
}
```

Can anybody help me to get this working?

Comment: @rmaddy:
I have objects in an array, one of the properties from this object is stockPurchasePrice. I want to take from all objects the stockPurchasePrice and see the value in totalSumPurchased

Comment: I understand that. And that is what your code appears to do. So what is the problem you are having with the code you posted? We know what you want to do. Tell us what problem you are having.

Comment: I get the following message in Xcode: property "stockPurchasePrice" not found on object of type "id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
totalSumPurchased = totalSumPurchased + [[self.arrPurchaseActions[i].stockPurchasePrice];
```

needs to be:

```
totalSumPurchased = totalSumPurchased + [[self.arrPurchaseActions[i] stockPurchasePrice];
```

You can't use the property accessor with objects of type `id` (which is what `NSArray objectAtIndex:` returns). Instead, call the getter method for the property.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSNumber * sum = [self.arrPurchaseActions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.stockPurchasePrice"];
```